# DRF - AttributeError when using ModelSerializer to save manyToMany relation with 'though' table

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am building a Django Rest Framework project and I'm encountering an attribute error that I cannot seem to resolve. Specifically, I'm getting the following error when I try to serialize a Sale object:

```
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `product` on serializer `SaleItemSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Product` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Product' object has no attribute 'product'.
```

I've defined my models and serializers as follows:

```
# Models
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class Sale(models.Model):
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='sales', through='SaleItem')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


class SaleItem(models.Model):
    sale = models.ForeignKey(Sale, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


# Serializers
class SaleItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SaleItem
        fields = ['product', 'quantity', 'value']


class SaleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = SaleItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        sale_items_data = validated_data.pop('products')
        sale = Sale.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for sale_item in sale_items_data:
            SaleItem.objects.create(sale=sale, **sale_item) # The erro
        return sale
```

The code I'm using for the serializers is basically this documentation example: [DRF Writable Nested Serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) the only difference is that SaleItem is an Through table for the manyToMany relation instead of a "normal" table.

I've tried changing the SaleItem object creation line to passing the data back to the serializer but that way the serializer as never valid and changing it to be valid for creation breaks the field for the SaleSerializer.

I suspect the issue is with the SaleItemSerializer or the SaleSerializer create method, but I cannot figure out what's causing the attribute error.
The only hope I have right now is to write an normal Serializer and the whole logic but i really wanted to use the whole framework potential.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically because you are trying to serialize a `Product` using a `SaleItem` model. And,`Product` has no field called `product`.

You can, for instance, add a related name to `SaleItem` `sales` field:

models.py

```py
class SaleItem(models.Model):
    sale = models.ForeignKey(
        Sale,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='items'
    )
    ...
```

And, use this to access `SaleItem`(and consequently the `Product`) related with that `Sale` instance together with [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield):

```py
class SaleItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SaleItem
        fields = ['product', 'quantity', 'price']

class SaleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_products(self, instance):
        qs = instance.items.all()
        serializer = SaleItemSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

Also, note that there is no `value` field in `SaleItem`, it is called `price`.

Regarding creating objects, that will heavily depend on the payload you are sending, here is a simple example, assuming the products exists on the database and with no treatment otherwise:

payload

```
{
    "sale_items":
    [
        {
            "product": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 123.12
        },
        {
            "product": 2,
            "quantity": 2,
            "price": 234.23
        },
        {
            "product": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "price": 456.45
        }
    ]
}
```

Then we can override the create method on the ViewSet, and pass data via [extra context](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context) to the serializer:

views.py

```py
class SalesViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Sale.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SaleSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        sale_items = request.data.pop('sale_items')
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, context={'sale_items': sale_items})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        self.perform_create(serializer)
        headers = self. get_success_headers(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

serializers.py

```py
class SaleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    
    def get_products(self, instance):
        ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
        sale_items = self.context.get('sale_items')
        instance = Sale.objects.create(**validated_data)

        for item in sale_items:
            product_instance = Product.objects.get(id=item['product'])
            item['product'] = product_instance
            item['sale'] = instance
            SaleItem.objects.create(**item)

        return (instance)
```

Comment: This solves the error but it leaves me back where I started, the create method don't work because the the MethodField is read-only, exactly like the own [ManyToMany relation with the through table](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#manytomanyfields-with-a-through-model) which is the reason for the whole mess.
Anyway, thanks a lot for the answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer with a simple create override example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer really clarified my mind, just posted the solution i achieved using your strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Niko's answer I managed to get id done containing all the logic on the serializers.
As I stated in the comment and Niko after modified his answer to fit around, creation was root of the whole problem and SerializerMethodField is read_only so it couldn't solve my problem completely, so I tried to mix up the two answers by creating an MethodField Subclass who's not read_only, and it worked pretty well:

```
class ReadWriteSerializerMethodField(serializers.SerializerMethodField):
    def __init__(self, method_name=None, **kwargs):
        self.method_name = method_name
        kwargs["source"] = "*"
        super(serializers.SerializerMethodField, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return {self.field_name: data}
```

With this we can still access the products data inside the create method, but now using the SaleItemSerializer itself to save the subitems

```
class SaleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    products = ReadWriteSerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        sale_items_data = validated_data.pop("products")
        sale = Sale.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for sale_item in sale_items_data:
            sale_item["sale"] = sale.id
            serializer = SaleItemSerializer(data=sale_item)
            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            serializer.save()
        return sale

    def get_products(self, instance):
        qs = instance.items.all()
        serializer = SaleItemSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

This way I was able to fix the whole issue and kept everything inside the serializers layer to easily add new things such as a `size` parameter to the `SaleItemSerializer` which is a `write_only` param to specify the stock of the product which the quantity must be decreased as it is being sold.